# Contextual Action Bar (CAB) not fully visible issue when activity in full screen mode

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, android-theme, contextual-action-bar

I have a small Problem. In my application I have added theme on the application node through manifest as below.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Now my app doesn't show proper contextual action bar (see screenshot).

If i remove the theme then i don't find this error,but i need my app to be working in full screen mode.

[image: See Contextual action bar, is not fully visible]

**How i can achieve my desired result?. **

Comment: try it in real device instead of emulator

Comment: well i forgot to mention I am using Asus Nexus 7, android 4.4. And its very real.

Comment: @Kake where is your screen shot?

Comment: @MD Its attached above.

Comment: @androidsanta ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of your text selection. so if you want you can avoid edit text selection by

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

I hope it'll resolve your problem

Comment: but this will restrict the in built functionality, which is not acceptable.